# I created stack using linked list and in inputting character to make string. But it's not working

Tags: c, stack, doubly-linked-list

In while loop i am unable to enter character in val. Also I am making stack using doubly linked list but my stack is not forming, maybe node is not linked properly. Something is wrong in function create_node(). Then I am displaying stack.
Please help me to resolve issuses.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node{
    Node *prev;
    int ch;
    Node *next;
};

typedef enum SIGNAL SIGNAL;
enum SIGNAL {MEMORY_CREATION_FAILED, SUCCESS, FAILED, UNDERFLOW, OVERFLOW};

// Prototype declaration.
SIGNAL create_Node(Node **top, char c);
void display(Node *q);

// Driver Code
int main(){
    Node *top = NULL;
    char c, val=9;
    while (1){
        printf("\n\nEnter character to insert in string :");
        scanf("%c",&c);
        create_Node(&top, c);
        printf("\nPress ';' to exit or any key to continue : ");
        scanf("%c",&val);
        if(val == ';'){
            printf("\nexiting...");
            display(top);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Function to create Node and enter character.
SIGNAL create_Node(Node **top, char c){
    Node *tem = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        return MEMORY_CREATION_FAILED;
    tem->ch = c;
    tem->next = tem->prev = NULL;
    if(*top != NULL){
        (*top)->next = tem;
        tem->prev = *top;
    }
    *top = tem;
    return SUCCESS;
}

// function to display string.
void display(Node *q){
    if(q == NULL){
        printf("\nString is empty nothing to display");
        return;
    }
    printf("String is :\n\n");
    for(; q != NULL ; q = q->prev)
        printf("%d  ",q->ch);
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the typical problem of `scanf` not consuming the newline presented when the user presses RETURN, and thus the *next* call to `scanf` reading only a newline (`scanf(" %c", &c)` is the quick fix - note the space in the string).

Comment: `create_Node` returns nearly instantly (after leaking some memory). Assuming you are missing a NULL guard conditional? Might be a good time to look into how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

At first, please note that in

```
SIGNAL create_Node(Node **top, char c){
    Node *tem = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        return MEMORY_CREATION_FAILED;
    tem->ch = c;
    tem->next = tem->prev = NULL;
    if(*top != NULL){
        (*top)->next = tem;
        tem->prev = *top;
    }
    *top = tem;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

you are returning MEMORY_CREATION_FAILED. Just this.

Enable all compiler warnings. There must be some warning about unreachable code...

There is even an indentation left, and I believe and `if` got deleted by mistake.

#### about the code

You have a `struct` for a node, not for a double linked list. Sure, you can write it this way, but is more difficult and harder to reuse and maintain.

A list is a container of nodes. Nodes are containers of some sort of data. Each data record in general has a key, like an id or code. Linked list is an abstraction of a collection of something. You should write the code this way.

### Using this abstraction in your code

Your data record is an `int` but is named `ch` and used to build a string?

Anyway, about the `SIGNAL` `typedef` thing, you should just return the pointer: it is simpler and avoid thing like `Node**` in the arguments.

Compare with this:

```
typedef int Data;

typedef struct a_node
{
    Data*   data;

    struct a_node *prev;
    struct a_node *next;

} Node;

typedef struct
{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

    int size;

}   List;

List *create_list();
int   insert_list(Data *, List *);
int   show_list(List *);
```

The list contains `Node`. Each node contains a pointer to some `Data`. Generic. You can reuse forever.

And it is easier to read: `insert_list()` gets a pointer to `Data` and a pointer to `List` and does his thing.

`create_list()` returns a pointer. To a new list. Or `NULL`.

For it to be really generic there are some other steps, but just as an example see

#### create a List

```
List *create_list()
{
    List* list = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    return list;
}
```

It is simpler to just return a pointer. Another function should follow to delete the list and return `NULL` to invalidade the pointer. And having a `size` inside `List` will prove itself handy in the future.

#### insert_list()

```
int insert_list(Data *data, List *L)
{
    // insert at the head, return new size
    Node *node    = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->next    = L->head;  // new starting node
    node->prev    = NULL;
    node->data    = (Data *)malloc(sizeof(Data));
    *(node->data) = *data;  // plain copy
    // adjusts the pointers
    if (L->size == 0)
    {
        L->head = node;
        L->tail = node;
    }
    else
    {
        L->head->prev = node; // now prev head follows this
        L->head       = node; // and we have new head
    }
    L->size += 1;  // + 1
    return L->size;
}
```

Note that a new `Data` is allocated and created inside the function, so `List` does not depend on external data.

#### show_list()

```
int     show_list(List* L)
{
    if (L == NULL)
    {
        printf("There is no list: nothing to display");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("List has %d elements ", L->size);
    if ( L->size > 0 )
        printf("(1st is '%c', last is '%c'): [ \"",
            *(L->head->data), *(L->tail->data)
            );
    Node *p = L->head;
    for (int i = 0; i < L->size; i += 1)
    { 
        printf("%c", *(p->data));
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf(" \"]\n\n");
    return L->size;
}
```

Note that having `size` inside the list makes life easier: we can use `size` to iterate over. And to have `head` and `tail` inside the list makes for an easy way to navigate the list.

#### a simple test

```
int main(void)
{
    const char value[] = "wolfrevO kcatS";
    List *one = create_list();
    if (one == NULL) return -1;

    char *p = (char*)value;
    while ( *p != 0 )
    { 
        insert_list((Data*)p, one);
        p += 1;
    }
    show_list(one);
    return 0;
}
```

Here we make use of the 3 functions. And it is arguably easier to read: the list is created. "Stack Overflow" is inserted in reverse and we show the list

#### the output

```
List has 14 elements (1st is 'S', last is 'w'): [ "Stack Overflow "]
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters these declarations

```
typedef enum SIGNAL SIGNAL;
enum SIGNAL {MEMORY_CREATION_FAILED, SUCCESS, FAILED, UNDERFLOW, OVERFLOW};
```

are incorrect. You may not use an incomplete enumeration type in typedef declaration. You need to exchange the declarations

```
enum SIGNAL {MEMORY_CREATION_FAILED, SUCCESS, FAILED, UNDERFLOW, OVERFLOW};
typedef enum SIGNAL SIGNAL;
```

These calls of scanf

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

and

```
scanf("%c",&val);
```

can read white space characters. You should write

```
scanf( " %c", &c );
       ^^^^
```

and

```
scanf( " %c", &val );
       ^^^^
```

The function `create_Node` exits at once after the first declaration

```
SIGNAL create_Node(Node **top, char c){
    Node *tem = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        return MEMORY_CREATION_FAILED;
        // ...
```

So nothing is added to the list.

Also it is unclear why the data member `ch` of the structure Node has the type `int`  while you are asking the user to enter characters of a string. Why not to ask the user to enter a string?

Comment: Note that `scanf(" %c", &val);` removes the ability for the user to step through that message by pressing enter (any key).

Comment: @Oka I have not understood what you mean. I think by any key he does not mean enter or any control key.

Comment: The preceding message is `Press ';' to exit or any key to continue : `, and the return key should be considered an *any key*. Ignoring newlines to scan for a character removes this functionality - the user must type some non-whitespace character to continue.

Comment: @Oka It is unimportant because in general the approach is confusing. He needs to ask the user to enter a string instead of character by character.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow How can he enter string directly.

Comment: for this he should make 2d character array.

Comment: @Mr_Robot And what is the problem? He can read a string character by character using scanf. There is no any need to declare a character array. He will place characters of a string in his stack.

Comment: I understand every character is present in each node.